# Установка пакетов ПО на сервер

Tags: linux, bash

Как можно поставить определённые пакеты ПО с минимальными усилиями на LINUX VDS? Например:

`APACHE + PHP 5.4(и правка конфига) + MEMCACHED + ISPMANAGER LITE`

Что-то слышал про возможность сделать это на `bash`, но при минимальных знаниях в администрировании это сложно.

Comment: для начала нужно понять, какой у Вас дистрибутив (упрощу - какой пакетный менеджер). Скорее всего там либо apt (debian-ubuntu) или rpm/yum/dnf для Fedora/CentOS/RedHat. А дальше скорее всего будет просто. И это легче нагуглить.

Comment: Загуглите, в инете полно доступных статей на русском.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проще всего, быстрее всего, и надёжнее всего — из репозитория используемого вами дистрибутива операционной системы *gnu/linux*. с помощью используемого по умолчанию в дистрибутиве пакетного менеджера.

определить название/семейство дистрибутива можно, например, с помощью программы *lsb_release*:

```
$ lsb_release -a
```

или, если недоступна, изучением вывода команды:

```
$ cat /etc/*release*
```

---

какой именно пакетный менеджер используется *по умолчанию* — целиком и полностью зависит от дистрибутива.

Comment: Тут на одном форуме, один чувак писал что можно одной строкой на BASH....

Comment: можно. но написание длиннющей универсальной инструкции для всех существующих дистрибутивов (с учётом отличия пакетной разбивки в разных версиях) из сотен «однострочников» — это никому ненужный труд. вы можете сами отыскать нужные команды, определившись с названием и версией дистрибутива (благо их на просторах интернета — огромное количество): «название версия как установить пакет».

Answer (score -1):

Если это debian/ubuntu то есть утилита tasksel, где можно выбрать к примеру LAMP-server

```
$ sudo tasksel
```

или если fedora/centos

```
$ sudo dnf group install "some group"
```